# Changing the active product tab with an url in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I’m trying to change the active product tab with a link. I tried the following snippet, but no luck getting it to work:

http://www.remicorson.com/access-woocommerce-product-tabs-directly-via-url/

The website I’m working on is:

http://wp.petruss.pl/produkt/sportinghotelravelli/

And the behaviour I’m trying to acomplish is:

When user clicks on a **[Wyślij zapytanie]** link the active tab changes to [Zadaj pytanie].

When user clicks on a **[Sprawdź dostępne terminy]** button the active tab changes to [Rezerwuj]

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Michal

Answer (score 0):

Hellow!
How about just sending 'click' event to the "li tab" when user click [Sprawdź dostępne terminy] button?

```
$('#tab-title-booking-system').trigger('click')
```

--------edit

```
$('#Wyślij_zapytanie').click(function() {
    $('#tab-title-booking-system').trigger('click');
});
$('#Sprawdź_dostępne_terminy').click(function(){
    $('#tab-title-booking-system').trigger('click');
});
```

This code maybe works!

But, I think you need to know what that library(http://www.remicorson.com/access-woocommerce-product-tabs-directly-via-url/) does actually.
Happy Coding ^*^

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this a little? This is jquery, right? How exactly to embed this on my site? Sorry for beeing rookie